# On which core of the CPU does my program run?

Tags: linux, cpu

I found that there are 44 cores on my server. If I run the code on the server, which core will it run on?
Will only one core be used by default? Do multithreaded programs use multiple cores?
or
One core is used by default. If necessary, can I specify multiple cores myself?
still is
How many cores are automatically selected?

Is there a way for me to know which cores I am running on?

Comment: Kernel decides on which core it will run you code. Your code will typically not run on the same core all the time. Yes, multithreaded program can use more cores simultaneously. You cannot select more cores, if the code is written to use only one. Take a look at these very good explanations: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835046/multithreading-and-multicore-differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the program **bpytop** (https://github.com/aristocratos/bpytop). It is very is easy to configure, can let you know CPU usage by core as well as a whole lot of other features.